# How to update the status of a particular user type on creation of the User

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have a particular User_type model in my database. I use them to determine the types of the user and also determine what they have access to in my web application. I am able to set the user_type status to is_admin=True when using the create_superuser.

But the problem is that, I am not able to assign the is_manager=True user_type for a user when created using the create_user function both in the admin panel and programmatically. I just have to manually set it myself in the Django Admin.

models.py

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def _create_user(self, email, password, is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        now = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc)
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(
            email=email,
            is_staff=is_staff,
            is_active=True,
            is_superuser=is_superuser,
            last_login=now,
            date_joined=now,
            **extra_fields
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(email, password, False, False, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        user = self._create_user(email, password, True, True, **extra_fields)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        user_type.objects.update_or_create(
            user=user,
            defaults={
                'is_admin': True
            }
        )
        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    # CUSTOM USER FIELDS
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/users', blank=True, null=True, default='images/users/profile-pixs.jpg')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/%i/" % (self.pk)

class user_type(models.Model):
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_manager = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.is_manager == True:
            return User.get_email(self.user) + " - is_manager"
        else:
            return User.get_email(self.user) + " - is_admin"
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from .models import *

# Register your models here.

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password', 'firstname', 'last_login', 'lastname', 'telephone', 'address', 'zipcode', 
            'city', 'region', 'country', 'additional_address', 'picture')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': (
            'is_active',
            'is_staff',
            'is_superuser',
            'groups',
            'user_permissions',
        )}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (
            None,
            {
                'classes': ('wide',),
                'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2')
            }
        ),
    )

    list_display = ('email', 'firstname', 'is_staff', 'last_login')
    list_filter = ('is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'is_active', 'groups')
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ('groups', 'user_permissions',)


admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
admin.site.register(user_type)
```

Comment: Hva you registered your model to Django's admin ? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example

Comment: yes i have registered them

Comment: Can you then edit with your admin.py file since the problem more than likely comes from there ?

Comment: i can edit them. I can even set the user_type for the user there but I need a way to set it from my models so that when a user is created. It is automatically assigned the is_manager=True

Comment: I meant can you edit your question in order to add the admin.py file so i can take a look at it.

Comment: of course, I have done that already.

Answer (score 1):

From what i understand you want that when you create an User object from the admin panel, it is automatically assigned True to is_manager.

You need to add an **add_form** to your UserAdmin class.

```py
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
    fields, plus a repeated password."""
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        # You can change the fields you need here.
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'firstname', 'last_login', 'lastname', 'telephone', 'address', 'zipcode', 'city', 'region', 'country', 'additional_address', 'picture')

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
            # create your user_type object here and pass it is_manager set to True
            user_type.objects.create(user=user, is_manager=True) 
        return user



class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):

    add_form = UserCreationForm
    # rest of your class code...
```

Don't forget the imports at the beginning of your file.

Comment: i will try out your solution now.